# Find the solution of the differential equation $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the solution of the differential equation $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=0.$

I though this was quite an obvious differential equation. Hence, I proceeded to solve like this:

> Given, $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=0.$ We can write this as, $$\frac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{ydx}{x^2+y^2}\implies xdy=ydx\implies \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x}.$$ On integrating, we have, $$\log x=\log y+c\implies \log(\frac xy)=c\implies \frac xy=e^c\implies x=ye^c.$$ So, the solution of this differential equation is $x=ye^c.$

However, to my surprise, the answer given is $\arctan (\frac yx)=c.$ Is there some mistake in my approach? I am confused about where I went wrong.

Comment: In a nutshell, both solutions are roundabout ways to express that $y=Cx$ for some constant $C$. Your solution is incomplete as $e^c$ is always positive, whereas $C$ can be any real number.

Comment: yeah I guess if you take the tangent on both sides of your other solution you would get $y = x tan(c)$

Comment: And... $\tan$ of a constant is a constant again.

Comment: @StinkingBishop yeah I am just reinforcing what you wrote.

Comment: How did you jump from $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $ to $ \frac {xdy}{x^2+y^2}= 0$ and $ \frac{ydx}{x^2+y^2}=0 $ ? Unless that is given in the question i don't think it's a logical step

Comment: @nickbros123 Sorry, the "=0" portion was a weird typo. I apologize for the confusion. All in all, what do you think about it now?

Comment: @Lemon Sorry, I didn't quite get that. But what do you think about my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using polar coordinates
$$ x= \cos \theta,~y=\sin \theta,~dx =-\sin \theta ~d\theta,~dy=\cos \theta ~d\theta~$$
Plugging into the given fraction and simplifying
$$ d\theta=0 \to\theta= c=\tan^{-1} \frac {y}{x} $$
The constant $c$ is arbitrary, can be converted to any other desired function of $c$.

Comment: Do you imply that both of the solutions, i.e $x=ye^c$ and $\arctan \frac yx=c$ are legit?

Comment: Yes, indeed. we can even legitimately  include any of  $ \{c, c^2,\tan^{-1} { c, e^{-c}, c+c^3, \log~ c/( 1+c-c^2)}\}$ &c. as constant to adjust expressing into any required elegant form,  because they all disappear on differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and multiply $ \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $ by $x^2$ (under the condition that $ x \neq 0 $ obviously) and notice that $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}$ is simply the differential of $\frac{y}{x}$.

Rewrite the above as $\frac{d(\frac{y}{x})}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2}$, substitute $t=\frac{y}{x}$ and proceed (integrate), you'll get the answer $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=C$ for some C (constant)

Comment: I understand, how the concluded the answer. But did I make any mistake in *my* solution?

Comment: I think in your method, you are missing out on another range of solutions because the integral isn't simply $ \int \frac{dx}{x} = log(x) + c $, it's $ log(|x|)+c$ .